# I received error 401 : unauthorized when accessing my web app API

Tags: sharepoint-server, 401

I'm trying to run one of my web app and it keep prompt me for user and pw thrice. then i tried running the API link by itself, it gives me:

> "sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" (access denied).

i even tried to change from **NTLM** to **Kerberos**. still wont work.

My Windows Authentication is Enabled, others offed. I'm new to sharepoint. Just started a month ago

[Here's the link to my WEB API Web.Config](https://codeshare.io/GAdjXE)

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is this web app? How does it authenticate? What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @wjervis I believe I'm using SP 2016 and currently developing a portal using SharePoint. I'm using ASP.NET. I have deployed some of my projects and activate some features. Whenever a user access the portal, it'll prompt for username and password and when a user successfully logs in, it's supposed get information and call the web api.